# Android resource compilation failed there is no error when i build but while running the program error occurs

Tags: android

I am beginner and trying build calculator app. There is no error when i build but while running the program. The error is

> Android resource compilation failed

How to resolve the error?
I have tried possible options.

> error:F:\MyApplication\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:188: AAPT: error: not well-formed (invalid token).

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/but16"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="53dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="258dp"
        android:text="enter" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/but4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="383dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="52dp"
        android:text="4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/but"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="39dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="381dp"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/but2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="190dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="381dp"
        android:text="2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/but5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="38dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="482dp"
        android:text="5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/but8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="481dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="53dp"
        android:text="8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/but7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="484dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="179dp"
        android:text="7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/but6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="190dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="483dp"
        android:text="6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/but9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="33dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="344dp"
        android:text="9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/but0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="190dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="341dp"
        android:text="0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/but11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="182dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="337dp"
        android:text="+" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/but12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="53dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="334dp"
        android:text="-" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/but15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="178dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="259dp"
        android:text="clear" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/but14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="192dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="257dp"
        android:text="/" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/but13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="39dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="257dp"
        android:text="*" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="314dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="66dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="251dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="70dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/but3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="380dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="172dp"
        android:text="3" />
</>
```

Comment: Your `</>` at the end should be replaced by `<RelativeLayout/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML is not properly formatted. The error is probably due to the last line.

***Change this:***

```
</>
```

***To:***

```
</RelativeLayout>
```